# Most efficient way to make a script run forever?

Tags: php

I need a script to work forever; that's it, it will generate information on the aground without stopping, downloading stuff and storing info on the database, as well as performing calculations.

It seems possible in PHP like here:

```
<?php
    ignore_user_abort(); // run script in background
    set_time_limit(0); // run script forever
    $interval=60*15; // do every 15 minutes...

    do{
       // add the script that has to be ran every 15 minutes here
       // ...
       sleep($interval); // wait 15 minutes
    } while(true);
?>
```

but it's accepted generally that PHP was not designed with this in mind.

1) Is there any drawback using the PHP way (How to stop this script?) or is there a better language to do this, like C++?

2) What other companies, like google who indexes the web, do?

Comment: You writing a virus? ;-)

Comment: No, how to write virus in PHP? I am writing a web crawling script.

Comment: I know it isn't php or c++ strictly speaking, but perhaps `cron` (assuming a *nix system) is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, no, I need it to run forever, not just at some points.

Comment: its called a **php daemon** - a google search should tell you all you need

Comment: Cool, but seems like a patch and not a professional solution. After reading the other answers, I decided to use a proper language for the job. I know C++ quite well and Java quite well. I am learning C#. Which is better suited for the job?

Comment: well that's a matter of opinion :-)

Comment: True, I am sorry if I was rude...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long-running scripts are generally a bad idea, as they're scripts for a reason. I'm not sure of a way to stop the PHP script once it runs, but there probably isn't a way to do so (at least practically). I'd recommend making writing a program that'll run on a server computer, using languages more designed to do that kind of work compared to scripts.

A simple C# or Java program can run forever, as long as you don't close it. You can manipulate databases by using the corresponding language's database support.

Comment: Do you think C++, Java or C# is suited best for this job, witch involves webpage downloads, MySQL writes and little data processing?

Comment: Zerox, ultimately it comes down to which language you feel most comfortable using. You will find that Java and C# have a lot of inbuilt functionality that will make your job easier, however c++ will likely perform faster.

Comment: It really doesn't matter; any language can be used to anything you desire, but I would personally go for the managed languages (C# Java)

Comment: I know C++ and Java. Is C++ suited for webpage downloads? I used Curl but I really wasn't impressed, compared to Java's build in functions.

Comment: AFAIK Java and C# both have wrapper classes that allow you to download webpages easily. Also, as Shane mentioned, Java and C# has much more inbuilt functionality, which may help you when manipulating databases.

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing is typically accomplished in PHP using cron jobs.

http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/a-primer-for-scheduling-cron-jobs-in-linux.html

(or google "cron job" + your OS of choice)

A cron job can be scheduled to execute an arbitrary script every 15 minutes pretty easily.

Designing PHP scripts to run forever is considered bad practices because PHP wasn't ever designed with that in mind.

Comment: Thanks, the code is complex; stopping is not an option, the script needs to run forever.